# Reverse search using pgUp and pgDn

Tags: bash, terminal, readline

I'm having a strange issue using pgUp and pgDn to auto-complete searches from history.

I'm using bash in gnome-terminal.

type:

```
vim fil<pgUp>
```

expected output:

```
vim filename
```

Actual output:

```
vim fil~
```

Both pgUp and pgDn are printing a ~ character on the terminal instead of searching through history.

I think I have the relevant lines in my /etc/inputrc but they don't seem to be helping. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's my inputrc should anyone need it:

```
# do not bell on tab-completion
#set bell-style none

set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on

# Completed names which are symbolic links to
# directories have a slash appended.
set mark-symlinked-directories on

$if mode=emacs

# for linux console and RH/Debian xterm
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
# commented out keymappings for pgup/pgdown to reach begin/end of history
#"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
#"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
#"^[[5~": history-search-backward #these are the values read gives for pgUp, pgDn. They don't work either.
#"^[[6~": history-search-forward
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word

# for rxvt
"\e[8~": end-of-line
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/DEbian xterm
"\eOH": beginning-of-line
"\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
$endif
```

And my ~/.inputrc if it's relevant.

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous off
set show-all-if-unmodified on
set completion-ignore-case on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat >> ~/.inputrc

"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```